# Spring data: Autowire JpaRepository (Generic type)

Tags: spring, generics, spring-data

I have a service (for generic type) which uses findAll() function of JpaRepository.

```
public class SomeService<EntityClass>{
    @Autowired
    JpaRepository<EntityClass> repository;

   JpaRepository getRepository(){}
}
```

But it gives this error:

> No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations

Is there any way to construct JpaRepository dynamically?
The service classes won't have specific implementations for each Entity.
i.e. I need to use Service class like this:

```
@Autowired
SomeService<Fruit> fruitService;
```

This means that, Service class won't know about entity class in compile time.

Now if I create Repositories extending JpaRepository, then it still won't work:
Say I create:

```
FruitRepository extends JpaRepository<Fruit, Long>
PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>
```

then spring gives this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2

I am having to do this:

```
public class PersonService<Person>{
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repository;
   JpaRepository getRepository() {return repository;}
}
```

Of course my entities are not really Fruit and Person, but the main point is all of them will have common "services" with identical implementations.

How do I implement so that it will be possible to define only single service class and autowire it by specifying entity class?

Comment: The only other method I have found is specifying entity class in each function of service, so that service can search for "repository" from a registry and use it to execute functions. But it is not as clean as I want it to be.

Comment: Why even bother with such a contraption? I find pass through methods a waste of time, just use the repository directly. If the services are just passthrough there is no added value in having a service layer. But that is IMHO of course.

Comment: Sure, I could use the repositories directly, but I still need a way to get a repository by just specifying the class of the entity.

Comment: Still why? You want a `FruitRepository` not just any repository. Also having a single service doing dynamic lookups for multiple entities makes me think there are already some wrong abstractions in your application to begin with.

Comment: Ok, I will re-think. But still, it would be nice if we were able to get class name of generic type in java.

Comment: The basic app I am building is that all entities will be loaded to their respective cache stores. Plus, all entities can be "looked" up via different attributes. Basic code is common for all. In fact, for loading into cache, everything is common, so I only wanted to create single service.

Comment: If they can be looked up with different attributes, you will also have different `find` methods which are only accessible if you have the specific interface at hand. Why aren't you simply utilizing either Spring Cache or using 2nd level caching of the JPA provider? If it is only bootstrapping, create an `ApplicationLIstener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` lookup all `CrudRepositories` and call `findAll` this would be especially workable when using Spring Cache or 2nd level caching instead of implementing caching yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82067/discussion-between-coolscitist-and-m-deinum).